# ViewPager никак не встанет вниз

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Здравствуйте. Я хочу сделать панель внизу, которую можно будет дотянуть до конца. Выбор пал на вертикальный `ViewPager`. Первый фрагмент внизу, второй -  тянется вверх до конца. В общем, вот:

**xmusic.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_background"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/pink"
    app:tabBackground="@color/toolbar_background"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/pink"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<ru.albatros.mp3.VerticalViewPager
    android:id="@+id/playerPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**audio_panel.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/play_panel"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/panel_art"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:src="@drawable/played_no"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/panel_toggle"
    android:layout_width="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple"
    android:src="@drawable/panel_pause"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:scaleType="center"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/panel_art"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/panel_toggle"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/panel_track"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/panel_artist"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**VerticalViewPager.java**

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());

    setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

        if (position < -1) { 

            view.setAlpha(0);

        } else if (position <= 1) { 
            view.setAlpha(1);


            view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);


            float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
            view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

        } else { 
            view.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}


private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

    ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

    return ev;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
    boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    swapXY(ev); 
    return intercepted;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
}
}
```

**PlayerPagerAdapter**

```
public class PlayerPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> list = new ArrayList<>();
public PlayerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    list.add(fragment);
}

}
```

**AudioPanel (Frahment)**

```
public static class AudioPanel extends Fragment
{
    RelativeLayout audio_panel;
    ImageView panel_art, panel_toggle;
    TextView panel_track, panel_artist;

    public AudioPanel(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.audio_panel, container, false);
        audio_panel = (RelativeLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.play_panel);
        panel_art = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.panel_art);
        panel_toggle = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.panel_toggle);
        panel_track = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.panel_track);
        panel_artist = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.panel_artist);

        return v;
    }

    void createAudioPanel(String track_name, String track_artist){
        audio_panel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        panel_track.setText(track_name);
        panel_artist.setText(track_artist);
    }
}
```

**Создание**

```
void initPlayerPager(){
    ViewPager playerPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.playerPager);
    PlayerPagerAdapter playerAdapter = new PlayerPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    audio_panel = new AudioPanel();
    playerAdapter.addFragment(audio_panel);
    playerPager.setAdapter(playerAdapter);
}
```

Панель сейчас сверху, а не снизу. И к тому же она будто растянулась на всю высоту и не пропускает нажатия на другие `view`, находящиеся под ней.

Comment: А для вашего кейса не подходит Bottom Sheets? https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-sheets.html

Comment: Юзал его, знаю что это, но планирую сделать пэйджинг экранов дальше. Тоесть первый - панель, второй и третий - полноэкранные